# How to create a group, add user to group, and give that group full access to directory in linux

Tags: linux, permissions

I have my local user `localUser` who has directory `/home/localUser`. There is another user `serviceUser` who runs some services and he needs full access to some folders in my home directory.

I want to create group `serviceGroup` and add `serviceUser` there. Then I want to give full access to `home/localUser/workingFolder` folder.

How to do that?

Comment: You should edit your question: define what you mean with "full access".

Answer (score 8):

- Assuming one user will be the user the /home is created for:

  -- That user would have ALL Permissions by default, as for the others  create the users and then add them to the Original users' GROUP

  -- Then make sure  the GROUP has 777 permissions

> ```
>     sudo groupadd serviceGroup  ## Creates the needed group
>
>     sudo useradd serviceUser  ## Adds the service tech user account
>
>     sudo usermod -a -G serviceGroup serviceUser  ## Adds service Account to the service group 
>
>     sudo chmod -R 777 $serviceGroup  ## grants  full access to the serviceGroup members 
>
>     sudo chown -R localuser:serviceGroup /home/localuser  ## owner stays  localuser but  anyone in the serviceGroup "group" has access to its full  contents
> ```

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: chmod: missing operand after ‘777’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.

Comment: still getting that error

Comment: `$serviceGroup` is a variable that is not defined…

Comment: I would replace `sudo chmod -R 777 $serviceGroup` with something like `chmod -R g+rwx /apps` from https://askubuntu.com/a/488491/48214

Comment: @Ryan, If I read your comment right, I think you are missing the sense of the question.  The context is an enterprise environment and you have some tech company's folks needing only limited perms and conditional access.

Answer (score 1):

This answer teaches you how to fish.

1. You want to use the `useradd` (or `adduser` on Debian) command to create the `serviceUser`.
2. You want to use the `groupadd` (or `addgroup` on Debian) command to create the `serviceGroup`.
3. You want to use the `usermod` (or `adduser` on Debian) command to add `serviceUser` user to the `serviceGroup` group.
4. You want to use the `chgrp` command to change the group of `workingFolder`.
5. You want to use the `chmod` command to change the rights for the `group` to allow `read`, `write` and `execute` access.
6. You want to use the `man` command to get the required detail info to perform the exact actions.
7. Start with the `man man` command.

Answer (score 0):

Check also permissions of /home. At least it should have execution permissions for all:

```
chmod 755 /home
```

Comment: I disagree. If that were the case there would 1) be no need for a `ServiceGroup` and 2) assuming enterprise as the question was worded (even tho holds true for home user but to lesser degree) would degrade security.